# Keycloak authentication with LDAP not working

Tags: callback, ldap, keycloak

```
keycloak.init({ onLoad: "login-required" })
.success((authenticated) => {
...}
})
.error(() =>{
console.log("failed to login");
}
```

I am using Keycloak with LDAP. The LDAP connections is fine and I can see the users of the LDAP imported into Keycloak.

When authenticate with wrong credentials, I see in the logs of keycloak:

```
2020-01-23 14:39:07,563 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-206) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=kfzbp, clientId=kfzbp-client-localhost, userId=null, ipAddress=192.168.180.26, error=user_not_found, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/#/, code_id=a58c68e0-bd96-47b4-acf8-ff0542d14eb2, username=dadawd, authSessionParentId=a58c68e0-bd96-47b4-acf8-ff0542d14eb2, authSessionTabId=BziTTLQWQcI
```

But the debugger does not jump into the `success` or the `error` callback function. But when I enter correct user credentials, I do not see anything in Keycloak logs, but the debugger jumpgs into the `error` callback function. But in Keycloak admin console I can see the active session. anybdody can help?